# Is it possible to add new functionality to OPC method saveBilling by Observer?

Tags: onepage-checkout, overrides, billing

I need to add new customer field. This field should be available during customer registration via OPC.
How I can do it?
I can rewrite `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` modify method `saveBilling` and add into it:

```
$this->getCheckout()->setSomeField($data['some_field']);
```

After it I can call Observer on event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order` and use such code:

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$customer = $quote->getCustomer();
$customer->setSomeField(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getSomeField());
```

And this field will be added to customer.

But I already have 2 time rewrites for class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`. And this one will be third. I don't like. Maybe I can use some event for it?  Or any other approach?

Comment: in which step do you exactly want this field to be? Should Customer fill this field, or you'll pass any intrinsic value in it?

Comment: It should be on Billing Step, when customer registration is possible, one more field for customer. Yes, customer should fill it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Check this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-to-show-validation-error-from-observer-on-frontend

Answer (score 1):

For adding a custom filed in billing step of customer registration, 
[this might help you](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page). For basic creation of custom customer attribute, refer [this link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6). This process has a considerable amount of coding and that's why I'm providing the link.

And yo! you don't need to override Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage :)

Comment: Oh no, it's too long. I can save needed attribute at `checkout/session` and extract it on order save. This approach much simpler.

Comment: If you're looking for a quick and simple approach, you can carry on, but note that, that's not the perfect way to do it. Anyway all the best.